# Is there a solution to get the statics of xray test plan in an easybi chart

Tags: jira-xray

We had statics in Xray test plan, and we want to create a chart for the same statics in easyBi.

In easyBI the Xray measure is not displaying the same statics in Xray test plan.

The measure we used is "Xray Test Runs", also some other Xray measures.

[image]

[image]

Is there a solution to get the exact statics of xray test plan in an easybi chart?

Comment: My advice would be to reach out eazybi support team; they are very good on xray integration specifics. Those numbers don't match the total test count, at least that should happen I think. Note that the number of testruns shown in the chart will hardly match the number of tests in the test plan, as one test can have 0, 1 or more test runs.

Comment: Thanks! I had found there a similar ticket. I am checking it. https://community.eazybi.com/t/xray-test-plan-execution-status/1574/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is to use the easybi new measure **Xray Test Plan Overall Execution Status** (notice that it is not possible to add custom fields in rows when this is used)
If still this measure is not yet available in your environment, you can also define it as an MDX calculation (see below link), but it is slow in response with large test plans.

https://community.eazybi.com/t/xray-test-plan-execution-status/1574/18